# how do I save from a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

```
  begin
  # make a new outgoing call
  @call = @client.account.calls.create(
    :from => '+1*********',
    :to => userphone,
    :url => builturl
  )
  rescue StandardError => failedWith
    # Create error entry
    Deliveryerror.new(:objecttype => 1, :deliverytype => 1, :objectid => announce.id, :errormessage => failedWith, :user_id => user.id).save

  end
```

This call is from a model called Usernotes and I am creating an instance of Deliveryerror. The call + save above work on rails console. I know the call goes into 'recue' but it is never saving a Deliveryerror entry to the db.

Env
 Rails 3.1 
Lion Server
Ruby 1.9.2 
PostgreSQL
*Using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) on this method call

Comment: Solved it by using Deliveryerror.create as opposed to Deliveryerror.new. Not sure why one was better than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `.create` and not `.new` -- `.create` will save the object while `.new` won't.

Comment: I ran .save on it as shown above but it still did not save. Thanks